# Why are callback functions not hoisted in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

I understand the concept of variables and function declaration in JavaScript being hoisted at the top of the enclosing scope. But if I have a named callback function, its not being hoisted. I am not able to understand why is that so. I have the code in the below link explaining the scenario

Example:

```
function enclosingScope () {
  var b;

  function inner (def) {
    def();  
  }
  var a = 2;
}

// After hoisting due to compilation, the above changes to 
function enclosingScope () {
  // Function declarations are hoisted before variables
  function inner (def) {
    def(); 
  }

  var b, a;
  a = 2
}

// But if I have a named callback, will that be hoisted?
function enclosingScope () {
  function inner (def) {
    def();
  }

  var b, a;
  a = 2

  inner(function cb () {
    console.log('Test callback hoisting')
  })
}
```

Comment: Q: What happened when you tried it?  Q: Why even *ask*, without simply trying it yourself?  You've *got* the code - what did you find???

Comment: I have edited the question. Maybe you can have a look now and help

Comment: If you are talking about your cb() function, it is a named function expression and you are passing a reference to it to the inner()  function. Function expressions are not hoisted,  and the name cb is only usable from inside that function - it doesn't create a variable cb within that containing scope, so there's nothing to hoist, and indeed in your code you never actual refer to cb anywhere else.

Comment: Hoisting happens `within` the context. Not necessarily on the global context.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: @AdityaParab The function doesn't hoist even `within` the `enclosingScope`

Comment: Function *statements* are hoisted. Function *expressions* are not hoisted.

Comment: But declaring the callback doesn't seem to be an expression but a declaration (or statement if you will). Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: It's an expression because of where it is used. Function statements stand alone. In your example the `function cb() {...}` part could be completely replaced with the name of a function that is declared elsewhere: `inner(someOtherFunc);`

Comment: OK. That makes it clear. Thanks a lot

Comment: @AdityaSingh : Another perspective that may help you understand better is - in your case `cb` is a `callback` function. The `callback` function are passed as a parameter. The concept of hoisting doesn't apply to the parameters. :)

Comment: @Aditya Singh - thank you for clarifying your question ... and glad you got it answered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior in question is not limited to named callbacks. It's the way any named function expression works. Consider the following:

```
function foo() {
  (function baz() { });
  console.log(typeof baz);
}

> foo()
< undefined
```

`baz` is not accessible outside its body. So this is a different issue than hoisting.

Answer (score 3):

I find the answer given is too short, so here is a more canonical explanation:

Javascript distinguishes between function declarations

```
function f() {}
```

and function expressions

```
var f = function () {} // anynomous function or lambda
var g = function h() {} // named function expression
```

Function declarations are statements, whereas function expressions are ..., guess what? Yay, expressions. Please note that the name of a named function expression (`h` in the given example) is only accessible inside the function body (of `g` in the given example).

Whenever you nest a function declaration in parentheses, it's automatically converted into an expression. That means your `function cb () {...}` is just a named function expression. But you don't assign it to a variable, but pass it as an argument to `inner`.

When it comes to hoisting in connection with function expressions, only the declaration of the assigned variable is hoisted. This isn't the case with function declarations:

```
console.log(f); // function f
console.log(g); // exists, but undefined
console.log(h); // reference error

function f() {}
var g = function h() {}
```

Since `cb` in your example isn't assigned to a variable, there can be no hoisting.

These two lines are therefore equivalent concerning hoisting:

```
inner(function cb(){});
(function cb(){});
```

**Bonus:** `const`/`let`

When you try to call a function expression declared with `const` or `let`, however, lexically before its declaration, a reference error is thrown:

```
console.log(g); // reference error
const g = function h() {}
```

`g` is hoisted too. But to protect you from unexpected `undefined`s. the interpreter throws an error. I think that is wise.